# nginx reverse-proxy simple config not redirecting

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

To get the hang of nginx with docker, I have a very simple `nginx.conf` file + `docker-compose`, running 2 containers for 1 service (service itself+db).
What I want:
`localhost` --> show static page
`localhost/pics` --> show another static page
`localhost/wekan` --> redirect to my container, which is running on port 3001.
the last part (redirect to docker-container) does not work. The app can be reached under `localhost:3001`, tho.

My nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
    server{
        listen 80;
        location / {
            root /home/user/serverTest/up1; #index.html is here
        }
        location /wekan {               
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
          rewrite ^/wekan(.*)$ $1 break; # this didnt help either 
        }
        location /pics {
            proxy_pass http://localhost/example.jpg;
        }
        location ~ \.(gif|jpg|png)$ {
            root /home/user/serverTest/data/images;
        }
    }
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'


services:

  wekandb:
    image: mongo:3.2.21
    container_name: wekan-db
    restart: always
    command: mongod --smallfiles --oplogSize 128
    networks:
      - wekan-tier
    expose:
      - 27017
    volumes:
      - /home/user/wekan/wekan-db:/data/db
      - /home/user/wekan/wekan-db-dump:/dump

  wekan:
    image: quay.io/wekan/wekan
    container_name: wekan-app
    restart: always
    networks:
      - wekan-tier
    ports:
      # Docker outsideport:insideport
      - 127.0.0.1:3001:8080
    environment:
      - MONGO_URL=mongodb://wekandb:27017/wekan
      - ROOT_URL=http://localhost
```

Looking at the nginx-error logs, I get this:

```
2018/12/17 11:57:16 [error] 9060#9060: *124 open() "/home/user/serverTest/up1/31fb090e9e6464a4d62d3588afc742d2e11dc1f6.js" failed   (2: No such file or directory),  
client: 127.0.0.1,   server: ,   
request: "GET /31fb090e9e6464a4d62d3588afc742d2e11dc1f6.js?meteor_js_resource=true HTTP/1.1",   host: "localhost",   
referrer: "http://localhost/wekan"
```

So I guess this makes sense because in my understanding, nginx is now adding the redirect to the root given @ /, but clearly this is not where the container is running.
How do I prevent that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was within the `docker-compose` configuration.
For anyone wondering, all you need is a proxy pass `addr:port` or `addr:port/`  whereas the 2nd option does the same as the rewrite part, so this can be skipped.
  Apart from that, i had to add the /wekan into the `ROOT_URL` inside my `docker-compose`

Answer (score 0):

Your nginx cannot access the local network interface of your docker composition.

Try to bind `wekan`'s port like this:

```
wekan:
    ports:
    - 127.0.0.1:3001:8080
```

Mind the `127.0.0.1`

See https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports

Comment: I changed it, it is still not working. I looked at the logs, I am updating my question for you to see it.